# Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: videoTrimModal is not defined

Tags: angular, uncaught-reference-error

I am working in video-editor in angular.

For trim video I am using `npm video-trim-modal`.

For that I have write code like this:

[image: trimmer component]

**But When I open trimmer component I am getting this error:**

[image: inspect error]

I have declare **`videoTrimModal`** still it says that `videoTrimModal` is not defined.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-trim-modal like they said try like this, var videoTrimModal = require('videoTrimModal');

Comment: also check our if module is imported properly , i can see a 3 dot after your from. That can caused by module import problem.

Comment: @Frost I can't use `var videoTrimModal = require('videoTrimModal');` because it's not for an angular, and second thing that 3 dot is not actually there, If we import any third party library and we import direct from `node_module` then 3 dot automatically appear there.

Comment: can you post your code and if not possible can you post a fake version of your code so that we can tell more about it?  (video timer componet ts - your SC says line 46 has a problem)

Comment: if u  put ur mouse for a while on the 3 dot ,it will say what missing - fix accordingly

Comment: i dont get it what do you mean by //because it's not for an angular,// ? your project seems an angular project it should work. if it is not an angular question then change question tag to javascript or anything you are doing